# HttpClient cannot send the same request multiple times in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono

I have a Xamarin multiplatform application and I need people to log into my application.  To check the credentials I have a API. But the code I created to call my API gives me the following error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot send the same request message
>   multiple times

```
    private HttpResponseMessage GetResponse(HttpMethod method, string requestUri, object value)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri);

        if (Login != null)
        {
            message.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Login.AuthenticatieString);
        }

        if (value != null)
        {
            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonString);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            message.Content = content;
        }

#if DEBUG
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate,
         X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{ return true; };
#endif
        HttpResponseMessage response = Client.SendAsync(message).Result;

        var resp = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return response;
    }
```

That code is being called on a button click by the following code :

```
    Models.LoginModel login = new Models.LoginModel();
    login.Login = username.Text;
    login.Wachtwoord = password.Text;

    var result = new ApiRequest()
                .Post("api/login", login);
```

And if I put a breakpoint on the line where the error occurs

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Client.SendAsync(message).Result;
```

I can see that it is only executed once.

**Update 1 :** 
The .Post function simply calls the GetResponse method like below :

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(string requestUri, object value)
{
    return GetResponse(HttpMethod.Put, requestUri, value);
}
```

Comment: Could you also provide the code for the Post method in the ApiRequest class? 


To me something looks wrong with the return value of the `GetResponse` method. You read the result in line `var resp = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` but then just return the resonse message it self. My guess is you do something similar again in the `ApiRequest.Post` method which will fail because after running the `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync` method call the `response` object is disposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you probably need to remove the line `var resp = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` from the `GetResponse(...)` method.

The `ReadAsStringAsync()` method will dispose the instance of the `HttpResponseMessage` class making it no longer valid. Since you do not return the `resp` variable but the (at this point already disposed) `response` variable, I assume later on somewhere in the code you make another call to this object. Which will result in the `InvalidOperationException` being thrown.

So try using the following function:

```
private HttpResponseMessage GetResponse(HttpMethod method, string requestUri, object value)
{
    HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri);

    if (Login != null)
    {
        message.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Login.AuthenticatieString);
    }

    if (value != null)
    {
        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonString);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        message.Content = content;
    }

    #if DEBUG
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
     delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate,
     X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
     { return true; };
    #endif

    HttpResponseMessage response = Client.SendAsync(message).Result;

    return response;
}
```